# Not able vertical align

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to align the text '**MyBrand**' to middle of the box(Highlighted in **orange**).
But not able to achieve that. I have tried using '**vertical-align: middle**'. But that is not working. What am I missing here?

**CSS**

```
header, nav, form, a, ul, li, form, img, input {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }


        header {
            width: 980px; 
            background-color: #6C8DD5;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Sentinal, sans-serif;
            padding-top: 7px;
            padding-bottom: 7px;
        }

        header nav {display: table;}
        header nav ul {display: table-row;} 
        header nav ul li {display: table-cell;}


        header nav ul img {
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
        }
```

**Html**

```
<header role="banner">

    <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li id="logo">
                <a href="home.html"><img src="brand.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="home.html">MyBrand</a> 
            </li>

        </ul>
    </nav>

</header>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: In this case, one simple method would be to set the line-height of the  #logo list item equal to the height of the image. Then text and image should align vertically centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/JCPy6/)

```
#logo a {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Would it also be valid to use a line-height equal to the nav height?

Answer (score 1):

Vertical is not as easy as this in CSS,

you should read this post
http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/
and this post
http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 1):

Add the below given code, `vertical-align:middle` on img tag is also important to remove margin from the bottom of the image. you can use padding to give spaece between them

```
#logo a {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#logo a img {vertical-align:middle;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vertical align just about anything in CSS:
http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at the 'line-height'

Answer (score 0):

css add id:

```
#inner{ 
  position: absolute;   

  top: 18px;    
  left: 275px;  
  margin-left: -50px;   

}
```

and in html

```
 <a href="home.html" id="inner">MyBrand</a>
```